# Monogame - How to correct “brightness-additivity” while using Alpha-Blend-State

Tags: 3d, monogame

When using

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
```

in monogame

following happens:
[image]
Is there any avaible method to keep the color brightness everywhere the same regardless of an overlap?

Comment: Your question doesn't have anywhere near enough information to know what's happening. Please post some code around the rendering part of what you're trying to do and explain the intention behind it.